# Relative layout error aginst google api7 build

Tags: android, google-maps, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to display the device's position on a map. i got my app working but the map wouldn't display. I've done lots of reading on the common errors for this eg map api key. my phone is a samsung galaxy 2.1. i noticed that i was building against google api8. so i mess up a bit on a few things and had to delete the project and copy and paste the src files back into a new project. the new project is built against google api7 now.

the problem is that the main.xml file has an error in it. The only thing i can think of is that i've changed what the project is built against api7 instead of api8. any ideas?

```
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').
```

[edit] the error is in the relativelayout tag

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill">
   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/myGMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="02wE28syQIHzpwXXa95CrtA1XJLU5segJgltvKQ"

     />

   <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext1" 
             android:inputType="text"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             />

   <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:text="CLOSE"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
           android:id="@+id/close" ></Button> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in api level 7 there is no xml attibute match_parent exist, instead you need to use fill_parent.